# Output node creation date between two fields

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, entities

I want to print the creation date of nodes of type article between two fields. I know you can do this with Display Suite, but I don't want to install the module only for this functionality. My only idea is to put an `if` condition into the `for` loop of field.html.twig to print the date after a certain field occurs, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need a module like Display Suite only if you want to do this in UI. For a solution in code you can add extra information to the render array `$variables['content']` in a preprocess hook:

*mytheme.theme:*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for node templates.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  $node = $variables['node'];

  if ($node->getType() == 'article') {
    $variables['content']['created'] = [
      '#markup' => t('<p>Node created: @created</p>', [
        '@created' => format_date($node->getCreatedTime(), 'medium'),
      ]),
      '#weight' => '5',
    ];
  }

}
```

Adjust weight to position it between the two fields.

Comment: Ok, one problem I just noticed: the markup is inserted in every view mode...

Comment: You can check the view mode in $variables['view_mode']